# vb.net - GMT Time?

Tags: vb.net, datetime, gmt

Hey, I am trying to get the current GMT time in vb.net and can't seem to figure it out. A lot of google threads pointed to using DateTime.UtcNow but that gives an incorrect GMT time. Any ideas?

```
MsgBox(DateTime.UtcNow) 'outputs 11/21/2010 14:46:41
```

http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/ gives a time of 11/20/2010 11:46:41

Comment: Can you show your current code and the output vs what you expect.

Comment: Yeah edited to show what I mean.

Comment: It certainly looks like you system clock is out. What does the "Time Zone" tab on the Date and Time Properties dialog show?

Comment: That seems to put you in the GMT+15 timezone. :)

Comment: Yes you were right. It was my timezone settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *is* `DateTime.UtcNow`.

If the output is "incorrect" then it's because either your system clock or your timezone setting is incorrect.

Comment: Why would my timezone settings affect anything. GMT IS a timezone.

Comment: Probably both. The time zone will be incorrect and the date/time adjusted to compensate.

Comment: You guys were right my system clock was set wrong. I guess I mistook how the DateTime.UtcNow function worked and didn't think it would be affected by my timezone settings.